# AWS Cognito: How to remember device in CUSTOM_AUTH authentication workflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have followed this AWS blog to implement the Custom Authentication Flow for my website with Email One-Time-Password as a second Factor:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/extending-amazon-cognito-with-email-otp-for-2fa-using-amazon-ses/

Basically it explains that on Cognito, how to use the `CUSTOM_CHALLENGE` and 3 lambda functions as triggers for Cognito to:

1. Define custom auth challenge
2. Create custom auth challenge code and send to user's email address through AWS SES;
3. Verify that the verification code the user submitted is correct;

The `authenticationFlowType` would be `CUSTOM_AUTH` in this case, which is different from `USER_SRP_AUTH` in the normal username/password only scenario.

Now, I want cognito to remember the device that the user is on.

In this doc:
[How do I use remembered devices in my Amazon Cognito user pool?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pool-remembered-devices/)

It says:

> Note: The remembered devices functionality works only with the
> USER_SRP_AUTH authentication flow. Also, this functionality requires
> multi-factor authentication (MFA) to be enabled for the user pool.

So how can I remember device when it comes to `CUSTOM_AUTH` authentication workflow?

If there is no easy way, then I need a way to send the device info or IP address to the Lambda function triggers that Cognito is hooked with when calling:

```
const user = await Auth.signIn(formData.username, formData.password);
```

to sign in.

How can I do that with AWS Amplify?